# I got a error message as "Error: expecting a single value" in dplyr. Why?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to give some condition to count and here is my code.
It seems to me there is no problem in my code. 
 Why this gives me the error as "Error: expecting a single value" ?

```
cust_online_trip = data %>% group_by(CUST_NO_ID) %>% 
   summarise(t_trip_before = ifelse(exp_mob ==1,length(S_TRHEAD_SK[before_1st_mob_shop ==1]),length(S_TRHEAD_SK[before_app_launch ==1])),
             online_trip_before = ifelse(exp_mob ==1,length(S_TRHEAD_SK[before_1st_mob_shop ==1 & channel == "online"]),
                                      length(S_TRHEAD_SK[before_app_launch ==1 & channel == "online"])))
```

Comment: It looks like you want to `group_by` `exp_mob`, as well.

Comment: You mean, I need to use 'group_by(CUST_NO_ID,exp_mob)' ?
No, it is wrong.

Comment: Because you are returning a value for every row in each `CUST_NO_ID` with your `ifelse` statement instead of summarizing to a single number. As @bouncyball says, if you also group `exp_mob` and then add `unique` around your `ifelse` statements you may get a single value returned instead of multiple values.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!